# Regex For Simple Pattern Matching

Tags: regex

How would one create a regex for a string containing alphanumeric characters to match everything including and after the first occurrence of a numeric character?

example

```
HdeTT55679HHdsdd
```

would match

```
55679HHdsdd
```

and

```
re678TTHY88
```

would match

```
678TTHY88
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[0-9].*
```

this will match anything after a number

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that the string only contains alnum characters, then you can simply match

```
[0-9].*
```

If not, use

```
[0-9][A-Za-z0-9]*
```

Answer (score 1):

use this regular expression `\d.+`

Answer (score 1):

If you're using [PCRE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions), the following might work for you:

```
'[^\d]*\K.*'
```

For example:

```
$ echo HdeTT55679HHdsdd | grep -oP '[^\d]*\K.*'
55679HHdsdd
$ echo re678TTHY88 | grep -oP '[^\d]*\K.*'
678TTHY88
```